# How to execute the io trace generated by DiskSim in real environment?

Tags: storage, simulation, trace, blktrace

I want to compare different disk models using DiskSim. In many studies using DiskSim, researchers execute the trace files generated by DiskSim on both DiskSim and real devices. However, I didn't find out how to do so.

Therefore, I want to find the method to run the io traces generated by DiskSim in real devices. All the kinds of format are accepted including ascii, validate, blktrace, etc. Please help me.

---

The example of DiskSim trace in ascii format:

```
ARRIVE_TIME DEVICE_NUM BLK_NUM BLK_COUNT R/W
0.46 0 50631816 8 1
0.53 0 50631824 8 1
0.53 0 50631832 8 1
0.54 0 50631840 8 1
```

The paper about DiskSim traces:
https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/fast03/tech/full_papers/zedlewski/zedlewski_html/paper.html
http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJGDC/vol7_no3/7.pdf

I knew something about blktrace, btrecord and btreplay. However, i cannot transform the trace from DiskSim format into blktrace format. It missed some io information.

Anybody help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to fake those missing information and convert `DiskSim` trace format into `blktrace` format. They use `btrecord` and `btparse` to replay those trace files on real system. The only information that you need to fake is CPU ID. Other columns important columns are present in your `DiskSim` trace. You may need to chenge the `btrecord` source code also to accept dismiss your faked information.

Your other option is to convert `DiskSim` trace into `fio` log trace and replay with `fio`. This option might not be as accurate as the `blktrace` option.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the tools you mentioned. It seems it's the only way to solve the problem.

Comment: Excuse me. The btrecord cannot recognize the format after blkparse. And I can't read the original traces  from blktrace without blkparse. Is there any  way for btrecord or btreplay to recognize the traces in text?

Comment: btrecord take binary trace of blktrace not blkparse. Use blktrace to capture binary trace files. Then use blkparse to get human readble files. Do not pipe blktrace output into blkparse. Then use btrecord on binary files.